# Perl match two characters with a repeat count

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to match and retrieve a sequence like `abababab` using a repeat count `{n}`.

This regex

```
my $rec = "xxxxxxababababxxxxxx";
$rec =~ /(ab{4})/;
print $1,"\n";
```

doesn't work because `{4}` refers only to the `b`. How can I make the count apply to multiple characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must group the characters that you want to repeat by enclosing them in parentheses. In a Perl regex, `(?:…)` is the same as plain parentheses, but doesn't *capture* the contents.

So you want

```
$rec =~ /((?:ab){4})/;
```

Comment: Thank very much. I really wonder where I can find such kind of syntax. I looked in several perl books and web-sites and couldn't find this solution.

Comment: Typing "perldoc perlre" at your command line will give you the full documentation for Perl's regular expressions.

Comment: @giordano: The pattern will work fine using ordinary capturing parentheses `/((ab){4})/`, but it is slightly less efficient because it is capturing `ab` into `$2` each time. There are many constructs that start with `(?` and they are called [*extended patterns*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns).

Answer (score 1):

"I would like to match and retrieve a sequence *like* abababab ..." (italics, mine)

Here's a more general regex for matching any set of two (non-newline) characters that contiguously repeats four times:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $rec = "xxxxxxababababxxxxxx";
my ($capture) = $rec =~ /((..)\2{3})/;
print $capture;
```

Output:

```
abababab
```

The `\2` notation represents whatever was captured in the prior capture group.  Thus, the regex 'says' "match two characters followed by three instances of those two characters."

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this regex-rule. Very useful.